# Programatically instigate a Windows Live Messenger Notification popup with VB.NET

Tags: windows, vb.net, live, msn

I really like the MSN notification popup. Basically the popup you see when you receive a new email etc. I'd like to put timers and set times so I, for instance, get a popup at 2PM saying "Don't forget..." I know I could make my own notification bubble but I'd prefer the WLM one.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answers in this question might help you: [Is it possible to programmatically talk to MSN messenger / Live messenger?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/506806/is-it-possible-to-programmatically-talk-to-msn-messenger-live-messenger). Looks like there **might** be libraries that might allow you to make the api calls you want.

Failing finding a way to talk to WLM directly, you may want to consider making your own notification bubble and make it look identical to the one in WLM.

Answer (score 1):

[MSNP-Sharp](http://code.google.com/p/msnp-sharp/) is a very good C# API that will allow you to connect to WLM and send messages.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look in the site [Live Services](http://dev.live.com/messenger/). You'll find some cool information about API's that can be used, but to do what you want you should look at "Alerts". This is the right way to do that.